# glGenerateMipmap doesn't work with 3D textures in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have several 3D textures and I would like to automatically generate a mip map for each of them. The textures are all 64x64x64 and I want the mip map to be generated just up to 16x16x16.

After that I want to use textureLOD to perform interpolation between various mip levels.

This is what I attempted:

I do this for each main 3d texture

```
glGenTextures(1, &volumeTexture[i]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, volumeTexture[i]);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA8, volumeDimensions, volumeDimensions, volumeDimensions, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, 0.f);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &volumeFbo[i]);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, volumeFbo[i]);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, volumeTexture[i], 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then, for each frame I call glClear to empty them and then call the shader that populates the 3D texture (it populates only the highest level at 64^3).

```
 layout (binding = 0, rgba8) coherent uniform image3D volumeTexture[N];
 ...
 imageStore(volumeTexture[n_tex], ivec3(coords1), vec4(fragmentColor.xyz, 1.0));
```

After that, before using the textures I call:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, volumeTexture[i]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
}
```

And finally, inside my shader I have

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler3D VolumeTexture[N];
...
vec4 color = textureLod(VolumeTexture[current_tex], texCoords, 1+distance/10);
```

since it didn't seem to sample from any lower level, instead of 1+distance/10 I put a manual number but I keep getting the same results I get when reading from the main texture. I put an lod of 100 which I expected to see nothing but the result didn't change

Comment: In OpenGL 4.0, there is a `textureQueryLod` function to get the correct mipmap level. Might at least help with debugging...

Comment: textureQueryLod seems to return (0,1) everywhere no matter what lod i specify so it means that it is not mipmapping at all

Comment: @tigeradol Have you figured it out by now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` or some other mipmap setting!